# TypeError: Requested keys of a value that is not an object. React-native

Tags: android, react-native

guys! I first making app with and have some problem with response values! When i click GO, i sent request and get response from it. Im looking in the console, i have 20 items from response on 'london' locate, so it works, but doesnt parse my json to key-valuse! Help me, please, guys!
Using latest React-native + android virtual emulator 7.1.1
Here is my code from SearchPage.js

```js
function urlForQueryAndPage(key, value, pageNumber) {
  var data = {
      country: 'uk',
      pretty: '1',
      encoding: 'json',
      listing_type: 'buy',
      action: 'search_listings',
      page: pageNumber
  };
  data[key] = value;
 
  var querystring = Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join('&');
 
  return 'http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?' + querystring;
};

export default class SearchPage extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: 'london',
      isLoading: false,
      message: ''
    };
  }
    
onSearchTextChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ searchString: event.nativeEvent.text });
  }

onSearchPressed() {
  var query = urlForQueryAndPage('place_name', this.state.searchString, 1);
  this._executeQuery(query);
}

_executeQuery(query) {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  console.log(query);
  
  fetch(query)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response))
  .catch(error =>
     this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
   }));
}
 
_handleResponse(response) {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' });
  if (response.application_response_code.substr(0, 1) === '1') {
  console.log('Properties found: ' + response.listings.length);
  
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id: 'SearchResults',
    name: 'SearchResults',
    passProps: {listings: response.listings}
    
});
console.log(passProps);
  } else {
    this.setState({ message: 'Location not recognized; please try again.'});
  }
}
```

And here is my code from SearchResults.js

```js
export default class SearchResults extends Component {
 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
      {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.lister_url !== r2.lister_url});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.listings)
    };
  }
 
  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor='#dddddd'>
        <View>
          <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
 
}
```

[Look at the error text ( in red pointer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiLNL.jpg)

[End here it is response from console. Look at the items count!So response works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXaQy.jpg)

Comment: I have just tested your functions - _executeQuery and _handleResponse in nodejs environment, and everything seems OK.

You should provide more information, e.g. what is this.props.navigator? Maybe the error is bubbling from there? Try to write try catch blocks with different console.log messages around every line and you'll see where the error is coming from, and hopefully that lets you find the problem?

Good luck

Comment: @Patrik Prevuznak, can you please give me more infomation about this solution? What blocks i may test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1-Try to put the `.then` right after `response.json()` like so:

```
  fetch(query)
  .then((response) => {
    response.json()
    .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response))})
  .catch(error =>
```

Update: Actually, changing the order of the `.then` is not necessary, it should work either way.

2-I believe that when you `console.log(passProps)`, passProps is not defined properly, therefore, `console.log(passProps)` won't print anything (Correct me if I am wrong). You can try this:

```
var passProps = {listings: response.listings};
this.props.navigator.push({
  id: 'SearchResults',
  name: 'SearchResults',
  passProps: passProps   
});
console.log(passProps);
```

I see that you are using `this.props.listings` inside your `SearchResults` component after passing `listings` as props using the navigator. The only way for you to be able to do `this.props.listings` directly (instead of `this.props.passProps.listings`) is if you have something like this in your renderScene method of your navigator:

```
if (routeId === 'SearchResults') {
    return (<SearchResults {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} />);
}
```

or

```
if (route.id === 'SearchResults') {
    return (<SearchResults listings={route.passProps.listings} navigator={navigator} />);
}
```

To make sure you are passing the props correctly to the `SearchResults` component, do a `console.log` in your `render` method of `SearchResults`

```
  render() {
    console.log("SearchResults props: ", this.props);
    return (
      <ListView
```

I believe that if you get the `fetch` output right (as an object), the problem could be the way you wrote your `ListView` and/or dataSource.

Other than that, there is not enough information (Such as the expected json response, and what you actually got) to tell where the problem lies.

Cheers

Comment: you absolutly right about console.log(passProps) - it realy won't print anything. If i try do that you say in first recomendation, i see in console: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0); Requested keys of a value that is not an object.; keys@[native code];

Comment: I just tested it and the first recommendation should work either way. You can leave it as you had it. [This is the response I got after testing](http://i.imgur.com/biCZuVR.png). Again, this is a json response turned into an object using the .json() function. I will edit my answer for some details regarding the navigator props.

Comment: attentively read you post, and it helps me again with new question:)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: look at the your post, i have latest little question to you =)

Comment: Inside your onLocationPressed function, you use wrote this: `var query = urlForQueryAndPage('centre_point', search, 1);` but urlForQueryAndPage is not called properly. Don't forget the `this.`, I'm surprised you didn't get an error for that. Also just to make sure, use `https` instead of `http` because ios (xcode) won't let you request from other server unless you changed that in the xcode project settings. Also when you `_handleResponse`, The response code is actually "200," which is fine, but for your function, if it is not 1, it throws an error (When it shouldn't).

Comment: Update on the previous comment, I just checked the API website and you're right, 200 is not the best response you can get, however, if your response is 200, it might not be your fault. The location given by your app might not be as accurate as the API wants it to be, or in the area that the API is expecting (probably the UK), use this location instead: `51.684183,-3.431481`. Moreover, make sure you are passing the props properly by putting a console.log() in every part that you think might have issues.

Comment: If you get an output like [object Object] like you said, more likely you tried to print an object as a string. See [this image](http://i.imgur.com/mkGL5UR.png) to understand what I mean. The object might have data but if you try to turn it into a string like the image shows, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: Next time please open a new question to avoid this long, character limited comments that nobody wants to read, you will also get help from other people who are smarter than me and you won't have to wait 6 hours to get a response. Thank you